# When I am using Maven Project, By mistake my project Name Rename with SeleniumPractice[SeleniumPractice master]

Tags: selenium, maven

When I am using Maven Project, By mistake my project Name Rename with `SeleniumPractice[SeleniumPractice master]`

[image]

please help me to resolve this query.

Comment: Just right click on the project hover on team and then choose disconnect. The thing is it is currently pointing to local git repository.

Comment: Could you please take a time to upvote my response if it has really helped to resolve your issue :)